# Enquiry regarding computed properties in React/JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently following along a React tutorial to create a form, and the formdata is stored in a state, and the values of each form input is taken from that specific state. I am curious as to why square brackets are needed around the `name` value in the code.

I have tried googling around and apparently it has to do with computed properties, but im not really sure why `name` needs it, whereas `value` in the same line does not need it.

The part of the code in question

```
function handleChange(event) {
        const {name, value, type, checked} = event.target
        setFormData(prevFormData => {
            return {
                ...prevFormData,
                [name]: type === "checkbox" ? checked : value
            }
        }
            
        )
    }
```

Code declaring state

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        'email':'',
        'password':'',
        'confirm_password':'',
        'okayToEmail':false
    })
```

An example of one of the inputs

```
<input 
                    type="email" 
                    placeholder="Email address"
                    className="form--input"
                    name='email'
                    value={formData.email}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
```

Comment: That's right it's a "computed property", which is basically just the technical name for when you want to use a variable value as the key in a key-value pair of an object. If you left off the the square brackets, the key would literally be `name: some_value`.

Comment: @Jayce444 oh, so its needed because in this case I am using it for the key?

Comment: Yes so because you're using the `name` variable value as a key, then it needs those square brackets so that it's the variable's actual value, and not literally just "name"